# Can I inject / run Javascript in different-domain frames in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

So I can run Javascript in the page that's loaded in a UIWebView by using `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`, but that will only run the Javascript in the top frame in the browser. I'm able to navigate from the top frame to other same-domain frames via `window.frames`, but that doesn't work for different-domain frames. Is there any way to access different-domain frames in UIWebView?

I've tried checking whether the parameter to UIWebViewDelegate's `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` callback has a different Javascript context, but it looks like even when the callback is called for a frame that has finished loading the Javascript context is still that of the top frame.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons javascript communication between frames is restricted to frames with that load their content from the same host (with the same protocol and port).

So the thing you try to do might just not be possible. However with HTML5 there is a feature called [postMessage](http://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage) which allows communication across different hosts. If you have control over the HTML content that you are loading into your web view you might want to check that out.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm hoping for some way for my application outside the browser control to access the frames inside the control. I'm working on a browser, not a web site..

Answer (score 0):

I realise this was a while ago but postMessage may do what you're after if you can control execution of JS on the child frame. You can use it to effectively pass messages back and forwards, and because you can build a rudimentary trust model around its use potentially even eval things safely.

If you never found a solution to this I'd revisit @joern's suggestion!

Comment: I do not have control over the HTML in the page, so I'm not able to add listeners for postMessage. I was hoping there was some way for me to run Javascript in the child frame from the `UIWebView`, but it sounds like there isn't.

Comment: There is a way to execute JavaScript in an UIWebView: stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString (documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: )